# slf4j logging not going to file after adding quartz library?

Tags: java, logging, quartz-scheduler, slf4j, logback

In my company we have our own implementation of slf4j logging and whenever we use our company logger, all the logs always goes to our own company file (host.log) and it keeps on rolling on some condition. This is what I see in our company logger that we are using:

```
// Internally use a logback logger which is a slf4j implementation
private final ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger m_logger;
```

But after I have started  using quartz framework, I am not seeing any logs going into our company file. All my logs from my classes are coming up on console only and infact quartz logging is also coming directly on console always.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    try {
        factory.initialize(TestQuartz.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quartz.properties"));
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
    } catch (SchedulerException) {
        System.out.println("error= " + ex);
    }
}
```

What is happening because of quartz framework? I have never seen my company logger to not work and this stopped working once I added quartz framework.

Comment: What version of Quartz are you using?

Comment: @Koby I am using 2.2.1

Comment: Is it possible your logback.xml file is overridden by a dependency? Try renaming the file and use 'logback.configurationFile' system property with the path of your renamed file as explained in logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html